# Jetpack Compose Dialog view size(Height or width) is not updated after initial recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a dialog where user have 2 option. each option have different Compose UI view. The problem is that the height of the dialog is never updated according to the user selected option. So Is there any way to change height of Dialog dynamically according to the content.

Here is my code which I am using to show a dialog

```
var type = remember { mutableStateOf("Adult") }
Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() }, properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = true, dismissOnClickOutside = true
        ),
    ) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            elevation = 8.dp
        ) {
            Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(top = 10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Row() {
            SemiBoldTextSmall(
                text = "Adult",
                textColor = if (type.value == "Adult") Color.Black else Color.LightGray,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clickable {
                        type.value = "Adult"
                    })
            SemiBoldTextSmall(text = "Kids",
                textColor = if (type.value == "Kids") Color.Black else Color.LightGray,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clickable {
                        type.value = "Kids"
                    })
        }
        if (type.value == "Kids") {
            EditBox(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 10.dp, start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
                .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = Color.LightGray,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                )
                .wrapContentSize(),
                placeholder = "Mobile Number",
                text = "",
                textSize = 14.sp,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                onValueChange = {
                })
        } else {
            EditBox(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 30.dp, start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
                .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = Color.LightGray,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                )
                .wrapContentSize(),
                placeholder = "Name",
                text = "",
                textSize = 14.sp,
                onValueChange = {

                })

            EditBox(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 10.dp, start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
                .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = Color.LightGray,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                )
                .wrapContentSize(),
                placeholder = "Mobile Number",
                text = "",
                textSize = 14.sp,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                onValueChange = {
                })
        }

        SemiBoldTextSmall(text = "+ ADD",
            textColor = Color.White,
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 30.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = greenColor, shape = RectangleShape)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .clickable {
                    onSubmit()
                })
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a known issue. Dialog view size is not getting updated after the first recomposition. Check the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221643630) and try the workaround addig in the `Dialog` the attribute `properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Modifier.requiredHeight()` instead of `height()`
[Modifier.requiredHeight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#requiredwidth): Declare the height of the content to be exactly the same as the min or max intrinsic height of the content.